# current_url() vs. " " in an href

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, href

I want to have links that allow for page refreshing and setting `href=""` seems reasonable.

I'm using Codeigniter (PHP framework) which has a function `current_url()` so I could also write `href="<?=current_url()?>"` but I won't do that unless there's some reason `href=""` is bad.

Am I missing anything on the usefulness of `href="<?=current_url()?>"`?

***note:*** I imagine most frameworks/languages have something similar to `current_url()` so my question is more general about the downsides of writing `href=""`.

Comment: Why would `href` be bad? What could be any downside of using it? I don't get it.

Comment: I don't get it either. I am using Codeigniter for 6 months now and it works great. Never used current_url

Comment: From the rfc 2396  **4.2. Same-document References**
_A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document, and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference to the identified fragment of that document._

Comment: @t.niese this should be an answer and the correct one :)

Comment: @Gerep well the question is if there are downsides. And i don't know if there are some browser issues. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is when you have a  base tag in your head. Otherwise they should be identical.

With a `<base href='www.test.com'>` in your head then href='' will resolve to relative to the base.

Answer (score 1):

I read that some browsers had bugs with `href=""` in the past.  Even though new browsers shouldn't have a problem with href=""; I'd go with `href="<?=current_url()?>"` to avoid running into bugs with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine any downside, really. It's what I'd do.

If you're curious about other options, you could also use the Javascript method `window.location.reload();` for the same effect.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend javascript for something that can be easily achieved differently!

Comment: I agree on both counts, just tossing it out there. But yeah, there's not much reason to use Javascript when it's something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to your own page might have advantages considering SEO, other than that I don't know of any advantages/disadvantages.